# Does Azure Offline Sync deals with relational tables?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, relational-model

I have made two table one is **User** and the other one is **Todoitems**. Todoitems are created against a specific user id but when i try to fetch them using linq query in *RefreshItemsFromTableAsync()* function, it compiles successfully but gives error on the emulator saying *"The member userid is not supported in 'Where' Mobile Services Query expression **item.User.Userid** "*
Following is my Linq query

```
var list = await toDoTable.Where(item => item.User.UserId ==1).ToListAsync();
```

I also have read on a blog that Offline Sync does not allow core data relationships? Any help!

Answer (score 0):

Offline Sync does not natively support relationships.  At all.  In any form.

For more information on relationships, see my blog post on the subject:  https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-26-relationship-advice/

Comment: alright then can you guide me a bit if i have relationship as mentioned in the link (i.e one to many) you gave, how I am going to display them on mobile Front-End as on the bases of foreign key. See my Linq query in the first post that is what i'm trying to retrieve on the base of foreign key match but it's not working. Even the application crashes. Anything would be appreciable!!

Comment: Any Help regarding the mentioned problem?